# User does not have any Google Analytics account

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

My boss registered an Google Analytics account and shared his website Analytics account with me.

Now I have the authority to see all data about the website.  I want to use the Google Analytics API to request data from Google Analytics with my php script.

Authorization is done without any problems, until the script tries to access data. The return code is 403, and error message is :

> User does not have any Google Analytics account。

Answer (score 2):

This will depend on what method of authentication you are using.

**Oauth2:**

When your PHP script pops up and asks a user to authenticate the Google account the user users to authenticate must have access to a Google analytics account.  In this case it doesn't.   Note: the user is only going to be able to see there own Google Analytics data not date for your website unless your boss goes and grants them access as well.

**service account:**

In the event you are using a service account to authenticate.  The service account by default doesn't have access to any Google Analytics accounts you need to grant it access just like your boss granted you access.  Take the service account email address from Google Developer console and add it at the ACCOUNT level it must be the ACCOUNT level to the Google Analytics website.  then the service account will have access to the data for that account.

Comment: On my permissions page,it shows  my service account email address  has already added to the ACCOUNT level.Is that ok?? http://a2.qpic.cn/psb?/V14fKlQ81KNYiz/X5UIG0DOXRU2fAnVKLcdKL5d.PLJYkOVHJ57obClU6U!/b/dCsAAAAAAAAA&bo=6AKTAQAAAAADB1o!&rf=viewer_4

Comment: On the google Analytics website top of the page Admin -> user management (under Account) add the service account email address as a user.